# Add a property to a child entity in an association with Doctrine's QueryBuilder

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, associations, query-builder

I'm working with Symfony 2.3 and doctrine 1.2

I have the following entity structure, with Product, Tag and TagCategory. Product has a ManyToMany relationship with Tag, and Tag has a ManyToOne relationship with TagCategory

Product class:

```
class Product
{
    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection List of tags
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag", inversedBy="products")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="tags_productos",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="cod_pro", referencedColumnName="cod_pro")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="cod_tag", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    protected $tags;
}
```

TagCategory class:

```
class TagCategory extends BaseTagCategory
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Tag", mappedBy="category", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    protected $tags;
}
```

Tag class:

```
class Tag extends BaseTag
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TagCategory", inversedBy="tags")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $category;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection List of products that have this tag assigned
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="tags")
     */
    protected $products;
}
```

What I need to do is, for a given list of products, get the Tags that these products have, and, for each Tag, get the number of products that have that Tag.

I also want to retrieve the tags grouped by TagCategory because they need to be rendered grouped.

Here is one of the queries I tried, it's on **TagCategory** Repository:

```
$qb->select('c as tagCategory, t as tag, COUNT(t) as total')
        ->from($this->_entityName, 'c')
        ->leftJoin('c.tags', 't')
        ->leftJoin('t.products', 'p')
        ->where(
            $qb->expr()->in('p.id', $productsIds)
            )
        ->groupBy('t.id')
    ;
```

This gives me an array with the following structure:

```
array(3) {
    [0]=> array(2) {
        ["tagCategory"]=> array(4) {
            ["id"]=>
            ["name"]=>
            ["slug"]=>
            ["tags"]=> array(2) {
                [0]=> array(4) {
                    ["id"]=>
                    ["order"]=>
                    ["name"]=>
                    ["slug"]=>
                }
                [1]=> array(4) {
                    ["id"]=>
                    ["order"]=>
                    ["name"]=>
                    ["slug"]=>
                }
            }
        }
        ["total"]=>
}
```

This query groups all the tags in a category, which is what I want, but it puts the total in the top level and as the total of the last tag in the category. I need the total as another property of the **Tag** entity.

I also have tried doing this query, in **Tag** repository:

```
$qb->select('c as tagCategory, t as tag, COUNT(t) as total')
        ->from($this->_entityName, 't')
        ->leftJoin('t.category', 'c')
        ->leftJoin('t.products', 'p')
        ->where(
            $qb->expr()->in('p.id', $productsIds)
            )
        ->groupBy('t.id')
    ;
```

This query gives me an array of tags, with the category and the total as a property, which is correct, but I need the tags to be grouped inside a category:

```
array(4) {
    [0]=> array(2) {
        ["tag"]=> array(5) {
            ["id"]=>
            ["order"]=>
            ["name"]=>
            ["slug"]=>
            ["category"]=> array(3) {
                ["id"]=>
                ["name"]=>
                ["slug"]=>
            }
        }
        ["total"]=>
}
```

I need something like this, can it be done?

```
array(3) {
    [0]=> array(2) {
        ["tagCategory"]=> array(4) {
            ["id"]=>
            ["name"]=>
            ["slug"]=>
            ["tags"]=> array(2) {
                [0]=> array(4) {
                    ["id"]=>
                    ["order"]=>
                    ["name"]=>
                    ["slug"]=>
                    **["total"]=>**
                }
                [1]=> array(4) {
                    ["id"]=>
                    ["order"]=>
                    ["name"]=>
                    ["slug"]=>
                    **["total"]=>**
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do, cannot be done with a single query on the SQL level.

You can do it with 2 queries or 1 query with subquery.
Still doctrine could probably do it in the background, but as I don't think that doctrine2.* can do it. I doubt doctrine1.* would be able to.

Anyway, if you don't need all data from the tagCategory, the best solution would be to modify your second query, and select the additional field(s) you need.

```
$qb->select('c as tagCategory, t as tag, COUNT(t) as total, c.name as tagCategory_name')
    ->from($this->_entityName, 't')
    ->leftJoin('t.category', 'c')
    ->leftJoin('t.products', 'p')
    ->where(
        $qb->expr()->in('p.id', $productsIds)
        )

    ->groupBy('t.id')
;
```

If you need, all the data, and the exact structure as you described, select all tagCategories with one query and then pair it in a foreach loop, by the id.

Answer (score 0):

In below code had some mistack

*joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="cod_pro", referencedColumnName="cod_pro")},*

should be

*joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="cod_pro", referencedColumnName="id")},*

Comment: The primary key column in Product is called "cod_pro", that's why I used that referencedColumnName

Comment: Here I have done this type of code, it will help you $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('S')->select('S')                 ->join('S.songsPlaylists', 'ap', Expr\Join::WITH, 'ap.id = :user')        ->setParameter('user', $user)->getQuery();

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't work for me either, it doesn't group tags inside categories